# Entity refuses to delete

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Entity refuses to Delete

```
 ...
    var ormPref = EntityLoad("Pref", {PrefGroup = arguments.prefGroup, Pref = arguments.pref});

writedump(ormPref);

if (isnull(ormPref))    { return false; }
if (ArrayLen(ormPref) == 0) { return false; }

for (var i = 1; i <= ArrayLen(ormPref); i++)    {
    EntityDelete(ormPref[i]);
    EntitySave(ormPref[i]); 

    writeoutput("deleted");
    }

ORMFlush();

writedump(ormPref);

...
```

The entity's definition is:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true">
<cfproperty name="PrefID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity">
<cfproperty name="PrefGroup">
<cfproperty name="Pref">
<cfproperty name="Value">
<cfproperty name="modifyBy">
<cfproperty name="modifyDate"   generated="always">
<cfproperty name="createBy"     update="false">
<cfproperty name="createDate"   update="false" generated="always">
</cfcomponent>
```

### Update

It turns out that it was deleted, an some other code later noted it was missing and added it back in. So the the function did work as it should

Comment: I suggest adding some writeoutput("relevent text") before and after the two if statements.  Maybe your function is returning false before you get to your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure something else is not adding the data back in

Comment: Isn't it the "EntitySave(ormPref[i]);" that's adding the data back? Not sure why you'd save immediately after deleting.

Comment: Aaaaaah. That is were it was. Can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 2):

Those deletes should be wrapped in a transaction block. Also, try deleting starting from the end of the array (not the start). Would be helpful if you would post the exact error you're getting on delete too.